# Using windows batch file to replace "." with underscores - without changing the file extension

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm looking to use the

```
ren
```

function in a windows batch file to replace certain characters with underscores. One of the characters I'm trying to replace is the period - but I need to do this without changing the file extension. Does anyone know how to delineate that a character should be changed in a file name without editing the extension of the file through windows batch?

When I've tried it replaces the "." before the file extension, rendering the file useless.

Comment: `ren *.*.* *_*.*`, maybe?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner that to be used in the *command prompt*:

```
cmd /Q /V:ON /C "for %A in ("D:\path\to\files.to.rename.ext") do (set "NAME=%~nA" & echo ren "%~fA" "!NAME:.=_!%~xA")"
```

Replace `"D:\path\to\files.to.rename.ext"` by the (path(s) to the) file(s) you want to rename, enclosing each single item in `""` (to avoid trouble with spaces, etc.). You may use wildcards `*`, `?` as well.

**Note**: The above code does nothing but displaying every file it *would* rename; to actually rename, simply remove the `echo` command.